# Ошибка 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyowm

Я только начал учить язык, не судите строго. Я яростно не понимаю, почему тут такая ошибка.

```
import pyowm

city = "New York, USA"

owm = pyowm.owm("1641c2adace3892722f516437cb094422")


mrg = owm.weather_manager()

observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
w = observation.weather

temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

print("в городе " + city + "сейчас" + (temp) + "градусов!")
```

во второй строке.

Comment: спрячьте токен.

Comment: попробуйте место `pyowm.owm` написать `pyowm.OWM`

Comment: Попробовал, не получилось. Какой токен?..И как спрятать?

Comment: и все таки, в доках -  from pyowm import OWM

Comment: В вашем коде написан ваш секретный токен. И теперь он уже не секретный.

Comment: я там изменил одну цифру. Все норм

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет правильно. У вас ошибку выдает из-за того, что написано маленькими буквами.

```
owm = pyowm.OWM("ваш токен")
```